# Catkin_make on the velodyne drivers fails in the windows 10 environemnt

Tags: windows, linker-errors, ros, lidar, catkin

I am trying to install the ROS-Velodyne drivers(https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) in windows to capture the point cloud from velodyne LiDAR but getting error while running catkin_make.

Since these drivers require pcap library, i installed WinPcap in my system and updated the cmake of velodyne driver to find the required headers and link the library.
But on running the cmake, i am getting error on "target_link_libraries" (image shown)

> Cannot specify link libraries for target "velodyne_driver" which is not
> built by this project

[image]

Following is the cmake file of velodyne_driver package:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(velodyne_driver)

# Set minimum C++ standard to C++11
if (NOT "${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPUTED_DEFAULT}")
  message(STATUS "Changing CXX_STANDARD from C++98 to C++11")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif ("${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPUTED_DEFAULT}" STREQUAL "98")
  message(STATUS "Changing CXX_STANDARD from C++98 to C++11")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
endif()

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_DEPS 
    diagnostic_updater
    dynamic_reconfigure
    nodelet
    roscpp
    tf
    velodyne_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_DEPS} roslint)

# This driver uses Boost threads
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)

# kinger: libpcap provides no pkg-config or find_package module:
#message (STATUS "****** Starting PCAP Search in folder:  ********")
set( PCAP_DIR "C:/workspace/WpdPack" )
#message (STATUS ${PCAP_DIR})
#kinger: Include file FindPCAP.cmake
include(FindPCAP.cmake)
#find_package( PCAP REQUIRED )
message (STATUS "******* FIND PCAP TASK FINISHED **********")
message (STATUS ${PCAP_FOUND})
message (STATUS ${PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message (STATUS ${PCAP_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message (STATUS ${PCAP_LIBRARIES})

#set(libpcap_LIBRARIES -lpcap)
if(PCAP_FOUND)
  # Include Directories
  include_directories( ${PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
  # Library Directories (Option)
  link_directories( ${PCAP_LIBRARY_DIRS} )

  # Dependencies
  target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCAP_LIBRARIES} )
endif()

include_directories(include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Generate dynamic_reconfigure server
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/VelodyneNode.cfg)

# objects needed by other ROS packages that depend on this one
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CATKIN_DEPS}
               INCLUDE_DIRS include
               LIBRARIES velodyne_input)

# compile the driver and input library
add_subdirectory(src/lib)
add_subdirectory(src/driver)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION})
install(FILES nodelet_velodyne.xml
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION})
install(DIRECTORY launch/
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch)
install(PROGRAMS src/vdump
        DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})

roslint_cpp()

if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)

  # these dependencies are only needed for unit testing
  find_package(roslaunch REQUIRED)
  find_package(rostest REQUIRED)

  # Download packet capture (PCAP) files containing test data.
  # Store them in devel-space, so rostest can easily find them.
  catkin_download_test_data(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_tests_class.pcap
    http://download.ros.org/data/velodyne/class.pcap
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/tests
    MD5 65808d25772101358a3719b451b3d015)
  catkin_download_test_data(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_tests_32e.pcap
    http://download.ros.org/data/velodyne/32e.pcap
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/tests
    MD5 e41d02aac34f0967c03a5597e1d554a9)
  catkin_download_test_data(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_tests_vlp16.pcap
    http://download.ros.org/data/velodyne/vlp16.pcap
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/tests
    MD5 f45c2bb1d7ee358274e423ea3b66fd73)
  
  # unit tests
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_node_hertz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_nodelet_hertz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_32e_node_hertz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_32e_nodelet_hertz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_vlp16_node_hertz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/pcap_vlp16_nodelet_hertz.test)
  
  # parse check all the launch/*.launch files
  roslaunch_add_file_check(launch)

  # unit test
  catkin_add_gtest(time_test tests/timeconversiontest.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(time_test
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${PCAP_LIBRARIES})
endif (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
```

UPDATE: Resolved the above issue. It was related to target_link_libraries where we need to provide the "target" and not the "project". I updated the cmake by adding this line:

```
set(libpcap_LIBRARIES ${PCAP_LIBRARIES})
```

Now, the build fails at 59% with following error:

```
C:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\include\diagnostic_updater/update_functions.h(188): error C2589: 'constant': illegal token on right side of '::'
```

Looks like this is an open issue: https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/280

Answer (score 2):

I'm happy to see that you are using ROS on Windows! I'd love to know more about your project.
We (Azure Edge Robotics, who maintain ROS on Windows) don't currently have a Velodyne lidar, so have not attempted to port it.

It looks like the Velodyne Lidar ROS node has not been enabled on Windows. It looks like there are several linux specific commands in the cmake file which need windows equivalents.

We have a porting guide for Windows here - https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/PortingANode.html

It there is a winpcap vcpkg which can be leveraged in the port:
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/winpcap

I've created this on the ROSonWindows github to track:
[Catkin_make on the velodyne drivers fails in the windows 10 environemnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64263546/catkin-make-on-the-velodyne-drivers-fails-in-the-windows-10-environemnt)

Comment: @kinger, as Lou mentioned, I do not believe it has been tested on Windows. I know there are parts of the architecture that are Linux-specific, such as unistd.h which is used in input.cc in velodyne_driver.You need to find the replacement for Windows.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT Yes, I have made those changes. I have replaced the linux specific function calls with equivalent function in windows. In the code repository for velodyne drivers, there is indeed an open issue for its support in windows. My first question is actually related to the cmake. If you look into my error, it is related to the linking of pcap library with my project <target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCAP_LIBRARIES} )>. If i remove this line, cmake fails at 54% with linking errors of pcap function calls (which is expected). Is there something wrong in this particular line.

Comment: @Lou Amadio I am trying to capture stream of data point cloud from the sensor - Velodyne VLP 32C. My requirement is to do it in windows. For this, I have two approaches - First, to port the existing ROS package to windows and make necessary changes to make it work. Second, to use PCL library and create a new grabber for this sensor (VLP 32-C is not available) by modifying the existing grabber. For now, I am more inclined towards the first approach but stuck with the posted issue. Since I am stuck in the build step which I feel is simply related to some linking issue, i need some help.

Comment: I'll take a peek at it.

Comment: I do not have a Velodyne Lidar (yet), but have made it build on Windows:
https://github.com/ms-iot/velodyne/pull/1
It is not currently tested, but we are ordering one in. Feel free to comment on the pull if you do test it; let me know how it goes!

Comment: @LouAmadio Thanks for the update. I checked the source and found it to be using Linux specific includes, (for example - unistd.h in input.cc). Could you share the process that you followed for building the project.

Comment: @kinger 
Install ROS Melodic using the instructions from http://aka.ms/ros. 
create a catkin workspace:

`
mkdir c:\ws\v_ws\src
cd c:\ws\v_ws\src
git clone -b melodic-devel https://github.com/ms-iot/velodyne
cd ..
catkin_make
`

This will build the velodyne driver on Windows. I am procuring a puck and will test once it comes in.